# How to show that this set is finite?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$
For $\alpha = (\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{m}) \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{m}$, let $|\alpha|:= \alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{m}$
Is the set $\{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{m}: |\alpha|\leq k\}$ finite for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$? I'm almost sure that it is but I have no idea how to prove it or even give a convincing explanation as to why that's the case. I thought maybe use proof by induction but the argument seems to be very complicated. Is there a contradiction you can reach by assuming the set to be infinite?
Apologies for tags, I don't know which section to post this question in.

Comment: It always helps to try on concrete examples. Say $m=2, k=3$. In other words, your set is a set of *pairs* $(m,n)$ such that $m+n\le 3$. Are there finitely many of those? (Hint: both $m$ and $n$ must be among $\{0,1,2,3\}$.) Can you now generalise?

Comment: A bit lazy and loose and bad practice to avoid doing the work of good practice, but note:  In order for $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...., \alpha_m)$ to be $|\alpha| \le k$ we must have that $\alpha_j \le k$ for all $j:0\le j\le m$.  So $\{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^m:|\alpha|\le k\}\subset \{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^m:\alpha_j \le k\} = \mathbb N_k \times \mathbb N_k \times.... \mathbb N_k$ which is certainly finite as it is a finite cross product of finite sets.

Comment: It can help to note that $|\alpha| = \sqrt{\sum \alpha_i^2} \le \sum \alpha_i$.  So the question as to whether the set is finite can be answered by answering "Is the number of sums of non-negative integers with $m$ terms that add to $k$ or less finite".  There are many ways to answer that there are only a finite such number of sums. (An infinite number of sums must either contain a sum with more than $m$ terms or a term that is larger than $k$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|\alpha|\leqslant k$, then, for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$, $\alpha_i\leqslant k$, and therefore your set is a subset of $\{0,1,\ldots,k\}^m$, which is finite.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\{\alpha\in\Bbb N_0^m : |\alpha| \leq k\} \subseteq \{\alpha\in\Bbb N_0^m : (\forall i) \alpha_i \leq k\} = \{1,\ldots, k\}^m
$$
and the letter set is indeed finite, as there are only finitely many natural numbers $a_i \leq k$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Prove that if the set is infinite, there must be an $\alpha\in \Bbb N_0^m$ for which, there exists $\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i\ge k+1$.